# Displaying paperclip attachments stored in a non-public folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, attachment

My conundrum is how to embed in an html page an image whose source is not available to the Internet at large.

Let's say I have, in a Rails/Paperclip setup, the following model:

```
class Figure < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :image
  ...
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   ... (authentication code here)
   has_many :figures
end
```

In the controller:

```
class FiguresController < ActionController::Base
  def show
    # users must be authenticated, and they can only access their own figures
    @figure = current_user.figures.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

In the view:

```
<%= image_tag(@figure.image.url) %>
```

The problem with this, of course, is that with the default Paperclip settings images are stored in the public directory, and anyone with the link can access the stored image bypassing authentication/authorization.

Now, if we tell Paperclip to store attachments at a private locations:

```
class Figure < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :image, path: ":rails_root/private/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename",
                             url: ":rails_root/private/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename"
  ...
end
```

Then it's easy to control who the image gets served to:

```
class FiguresController < ActionController::Base
  def show
    @figure = current_user.figures.find(params[:id])
    send_file @figure.image.path, type: 'image/jpeg', disposition: 'inline'
  end
end
```

The effect of this action is to display the image in its own browser window/tab.

On the other hand, `image_tag(@figure.image.url)` will understandably produce a routing error, because the source cannot be accessed!

Thus, is there a way to display the image via `image_tag` in a regular HTML page, while still restricting access to it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `:url` option passed to `has_attached_file` so that it matches the route for your figures controller.

For example, if the correct url is `/figures/123` for the figure with is 123 then the url you pass to `has_attached_file` should be

```
'/figures/:id'
```

Or even

```
'/:class/:id'
```

Since the `:class` segment will be interpolated to the pluralized lowercase underscore form of the name. You could also append the extension or the filename if you wanted (but you would then have to change the controller code slightly to extract the id)

Comment: As I understand from your answer, you are advising creating a controller in order to run some logic to check if the user whose requested the file has a permission to read it. And if so, by the use of send_file method sending the file to the client.?